# Demo application on Windows Azure Platform?

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, cloud, azure

I need a demo application to demonstrate about Windows Azure Platform. I tried [myTODO](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mytodo) project , but because it's not updated since Aug/2009, it cannot work properly (even after installing and configuring all needed components) .

Very appreciated if you can suggest me an open-source, free project build for Windows Azure Platform, which can run smoothly with VS 2008. This project should not be too simple or too complicated. myTODO's size is the best. C# source code is preferred.

Thank you very much, this question is urgent.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the project done by students. It might work out as a good sample.

### [Sqwarea, open source game on Windows Azure](http://vermorel.com/journal/2010/4/28/sqwarea-open-source-game-on-windows-azure.html)

> This project aim to be an in-browser, minimalistic, massively multiplayer strategy game. It is done as a part of the "Génie logiciel et Cloud Computing" course at the Ens.
>
> In the game you are a King battling over a gigantic map to conquer the world. Train soldiers, conquer new territories, and resist the assault from other kingdoms. You can read the rules here.
>
> It is a massively multiplayer online game: all the players are on the same map, which is an infinite 2D square matrix.
>
> Sqwarea is developed using Microsoft.NET technologies (Visual C#, ASP.NET MVC...) and will be hosted using the Windows Azure cloud services in order to be scalable.

[alt text http://vermorel.com/storage/thumbnails/5041097-6720829-thumbnail.jpg](http://vermorel.com/storage/thumbnails/5041097-6720829-thumbnail.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I recently read an article in MSDN and Visual Studio magazines that walked through a basic Azure project. Try

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/04/01/using-visual-studio-2010.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336122.aspx

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

The samples shipped with the Windows Azure SDK (1.1) should work fine. They're compressed in a zip file.

However please note that Windows Azure SDK only runs on Vista SP1, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I like the guestbook demo at Windows Azure Platform Training Kit, its easy and runs right out of the box, you can download the training kit at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=413e88f8-5966-4a83-b309-53b7b77edf78&displaylang=en